# Problems with loading pages using Cloudflare and Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, cloudflare

I have configured my GoDaddy DNS through Cloudflare, pointing at Heroku's URLs (ivanteong.herokuapp.com) after adding www.ivanteong.com and ivanteong.com to custom domains of Heroku.

I have also added the CNAME for ivanteong.herokuapp.com to Cloudflare for its root and www, configured "Full" for the Crypto settings and enabled "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites". This is to make the site appear as HTTPS. I have also added Page Rules such that everything redirects to https://www.ivanteong.com.

However, I have been facing consistent issues with loading the pages on my website, in order of frequency:

1) When going to different pages on ivanteong.com, it will sometimes reach "There is nothing here yet" page on Heroku. Sometimes, it happens on the main site, other times it happens on the subpages. Visitors need to refresh the page multiple times before the actual page will load and the error page on Heroku is gone. This is bad for user experience as most of the time, users won't bother reloading as they will think the site is broken. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the rerouting of DNS or the DNS connection between Cloudflare and Heroku. I'm on the free tier on Heroku, wondering if that is the problem?

2) Sometimes, some of the assets such as the Javascript library or images will not load fully, and the site will appear without the images loaded or the UI scrambled, only resolved when I refreshed the page. It looks as if they load 80% of assets the first time and only finish loading everything after I reload the page. I'm wondering if it is something to do with forcing HTTPS encryption over all the assets?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing a similar problem. When I try to load(via https) `https://example.com` I was getting no app found error. I fixed it by adding multiple domains in heroku custom domain settings. I added both, domain with www subdomain and naked/root domain to heroku and now i get redirection to `www.example.com` but I don't get the no app error. I hope this might work for you as well.